# How do I make a Posix thread finish its job after a certain amount of time?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I want to make a Posix thread finish its job after a certain amount of time has passed. You can see my solution in the simple C + Python pseudocode. But I don't think that is an efficient and accurate solution. What is the best way to achive this?

```
Mutex incrementLock
BigInteger n = 0
int milliToWork = 5000

Worker()
    int elapsedMilli = 0
    while elapsedMilli < milliToWork
        clock_t startClock = clock()
        Lock(incrementLock)
        n += 1
        Unlock(incrementLock)
        clock_t endClock = clock()
        elapsedMilli += (double)(endClock - startClock) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000.0

main()
    int nThreads = 100
    Thread threads[nThreads]
    for i = 1 to nThreads
        ThreadCreate(threads[i], Worker)
    for i = 1 to nThreads
        ThreadJoin(threads[i])
```

Comment: It depends on what _"it's job"_ is.  If it is to increment `n` as fast as possible, then what you have works.

Comment: @D.Shawley Well, I need to spawn several threads, and let them do some calculation together, which must be done within a certain time, say 30 seconds. So they should do their best within 28 seconds for example, and the last 2 seconds are for some cleanup job. Is my solution measuring the time accurately enough to do this?

Comment: yes.  IIRC, `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is required to be 1,000,000 by POSIX so it should be more that accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a timer to send you a signal when your time is up. Pseudocode:

```
sig_action_handler()
{
  /*cleanup*/
  pthread_exit();
}

worker()
{
  sigaction(sig_action_handler);
  timer_create();
  timer_settime();
  while(true)
    {
      /*do work*/
    }
 }
```

Alternatively, and for easier threading:

```
sig_action_handler(int, siginfo_t *t, void *)
{
  volatile sig_atomic_t *at = t->si_value.sival_ptr;
  *at = true;
}

worker()
{
  volatile sig_atomic_t at = 0;
  struct sigevent si = {/*...*/, .sigev_value.sival_ptr = &at};
  sigaction(sig_action_handler);
  timer_create(/*...*/, &si, /*...*/);
  timer_settime();
  while(!at)
    {
      /*do work*/
    }
  /*cleanup*/
 }
```

Comment: Agreed. But with the caveat that it is safe/desirable to abort "do work" at any time.

Comment: @AlanAu: Alternatively, you can have a `volatile sig_atomic_t` that is tested in the loop, and set by the signal handler. That way the cleanup can be done outside of the signal-handler context, in normal code.

Comment: Again agreed. But it depends on the granularity of the timeout (seconds, microseconds, etc) versus how long the actual work is.  If, for example, the timeout is in seconds and the work in milli or micro seconds then the OP's current solution is probably adequate and somewhat simpler.

Comment: @AlanAu: Eh, I've found this kind of timer to be surprisingly simple to use. I'm a bit wary of mixing signals and threads, however.

Comment: Yep. I meant the signal and threads aspect rather than the timer per se. Especially in this case where there are multiple threads. The timer solution would not work (or would require signal/thread/synchronisation gymnastics) if, for example, each thread required a different work timeout. Cause the signal could be delivered to any thread.

Comment: @AlanAu: The `volatile sig_atomic_t`-variant should easily work with threads.

Comment: You don't want to call `pthread_exit()` from a signal handler, really!